# is not distinct from in join on clause oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, distinct

I have a query structured with the left outer join like so:

```
left outer JOIN GA_LOAN GA 
  ON LOAN.LOAN_TYPE = GA.LOAN_TYP
    AND LOAN.DT = GA.GUARANTY_DT
    AND LOAN.FFEL_DUP_ID = GA.SEP_LOAN_IND
    AND LOAN.SCH_BR_CODE = GA.ORIG_SCHL_CD
    AND STU.CURR_SSN = GA.STU_SSN
    AND STU.DOB = GA.DOB
    and stu.curr_fst = ga.stu_first_nam
  --and (plus_bor.curr_ssn is not distinct from ga.plus_brwr_ssn )
```

When I add the commented out line, I get the following error.

```
ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword
00908. 00000 -  "missing NULL keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

is not distinct from works fine in this structure in DB2, but Oracle is giving me issues. Any suggestions?

I get no errors if I replaced `is not distinct from` with a `=` but that isn't the same logically.

`is not distinct from` with give a match if both values are `null`, where as `=` would not match in this case.

Comment: "obviously that isn't the same logically" - it's not obvious what that `is not distinct` should do (for people who don't know DB2). Could you explain the difference?

Comment: @Mat edit added for clarification...

Comment: What about `(plus_bor.curr_ssn is not distinct from ga.plus_brwr_ssn )` to `(coalesce(plus_bor.curr_ssn,'')= coalesce(ga.plus_brwr_ssn,''))`  This should convert null in either case to '' which will evaluate to true if both are null. which is the case I think you're missing...

Comment: Although that works, and I could rewrite it out in even longer format, I was wondering why the syntax of the `is not distinct from` is incorrect, or if it's even a valid statement in Oracle.

Comment: AFAIK, It's not valid in oracle. it doesn't support the `is not distinct`.  I've not been able to find it in oracle docs, nor reference to the oracle equivalent of this.

Comment: http://blog.jooq.org/2012/09/21/the-is-distinct-from-predicate/ seems to say it's not supported.

Comment: @xQbert `(coalesce(plus_bor.curr_ssn,'')= coalesce(ga.plus_brwr_ssn,''))` won't work, because Oracle treats `''` as `null`: **http://rextester.com/CKQY69225** and PostgreSQL version which supports `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`: **http://rextester.com/PUG42524**

Comment: Here's a good article on what databases support `IS NOT DISTICT FROM`: [Can I use… IS NOT DISTINCT FROM (null-safe equals comparison)](https://modern-sql.com/caniuse/is-not-distinct-from).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to emulate `IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM` in Oracle is by using `DECODE`:

```sql
-- a IS DISTINCT FROM b
DECODE(a, b, 1, 0) = 0

-- a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b
DECODE(a, b, 1, 0) = 1
```

This is what you're getting when you're using [jOOQ's SQL dialect translator](https://www.jooq.org/translate/). A [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8a935ca47fb9079dffa702b9251b4340) for this:

```sql
WITH t (x) AS (
  SELECT 1    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2    FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT null FROM dual
)
SELECT
  t1.x AS x1,
  t2.x AS x2,
  DECODE(t1.x, t2.x, 1, 0) AS not_distinct
FROM t t1, t t2
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Yields:

```
  X1 |   X2 | NOT_DISTINCT
-----+------+-------------
   1 |    1 |            1
   1 |    2 |            0
   1 | null |            0
   2 |    1 |            0
   2 |    2 |            1
   2 | null |            0
null |    1 |            0
null |    2 |            0
null | null |            1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could emulate `IS DISTINCT FROM` by using `NOT EXISTS` combined with `INTERSECT`:

```
plus_bor.curr_ssn IS DISTINCT FROM ga.plus_brwr_ssn
<=>
NOT EXISTS (SELECT plus_bor.curr_ssn FROM dual INTERSECT
            SELECT ga.plus_brwr_ssn FROM dual);
```

Example:

```
WITH cte(a,b) AS (
    SELECT 1, NULL    FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,2        FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,1        FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 1    FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL FROM dual
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a FROM dual INTERSECT
                SELECT b FROM dual)
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ZLNFU82378)**

Output:

```
A       B
------------
1       NULL
1       2
NULL    1
```

---

And in your case `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is simply `EXISTS`:

```
plus_bor.curr_ssn IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ga.plus_brwr_ssn
<=>
EXISTS (SELECT plus_bor.curr_ssn FROM dual INTERSECT
        SELECT ga.plus_brwr_ssn FROM dual);
```

Example:

```
WITH cte(a,b) AS (
    SELECT 1, NULL      FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,2          FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 1,1          FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 1      FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, NULL   FROM dual
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a FROM dual INTERSECT
              SELECT b FROM dual);
```

Output:

```
 A      B
 1      1
 NULL   NULL
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/HRHC28360)**

---

## ADDENDUM

This approach has one big advantage over `COALESCE/NVL` approach as proposed in comments.
You don't have to think about default neutral value dependent on datatype.

For example if column is datatype `DATE`/`INT`/`TEXT` then you have to write something like:

```
coalesce(col1,DATE '1900-01-01') = coalesce(col2,DATE '1900-01-01')
coalesce(col1, 0) = coalesce(col2, 0)
coalesce(col1, ' ') = coalesce(col2, ' ')
```

There is of course slight chance of collision. For example:

```
coalesce(col1, 0) = coalesce(col2, 0)
=>
col1 = NULL
col2 = 0
and we have incorrect match!!!
```